# why am i getting incorrect offsetwidth and increased dimentions?

Tags: javascript, html

- In the following link at bottom of this description, i was trying to make a mask box which incorporates the dimentions of the HTMLElement on which the mouse is clicked onto itself.
- But on clicking any element on the page, somehow the width and height get incremented when the same place is clicked multiple times.
- EDIT - Also the 'width' and 'height' of the mask div is bigger than
  the original element.
- In the function "scaleChange" when all functions of object "AspectViewport" called this auto increment problem arises, But it does not arise when even one function "left" of "top" are commented out.
- I have spent hours trying to figure this out StackOverflow is my last hope.

EDIT: YES the scale is itself being targeted, i am aware of it, But even if so, the dimentions should not get incremented.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0xp2um/1/)
The following is the JS

```
var AspectViewport = function(parameter){

    var elementObject = null,
        elementParent = null,
        _element = null,
        left = 0, _scrollLeft = 0,
        top = 0, _scrollTop = 0;

    function main(parameter){
        _element = parameter;
    }

    main.fn = main.prototype;

    main.fn.left = function(){
        left = 0, _scrollLeft = 0, elementObject = _element;
        while(elementObject){
            left = left + elementObject.offsetLeft;
            elementObject = elementObject.offsetParent;
        }
        for(elementParent = _element.parentNode ; elementParent != null && elementParent.nodeType == 1 ; elementParent = elementParent.parentNode){
            _scrollLeft = _scrollLeft + elementParent.scrollLeft;
        }
        return (_scrollLeft + (left - _scrollLeft));
    };
    main.fn.top = function(){
        top = 0, _scrollTop = 0, elementObject = _element;
        while(elementObject){
            top = top + elementObject.offsetTop;
            elementObject = elementObject.offsetParent;
        }
        for(elementParent = _element.parentNode ; elementParent != null && elementParent.nodeType == 1 ; elementParent = elementParent.parentNode){
            _scrollTop = _scrollTop + elementParent.scrollTop;      
        }
        return (_scrollTop + (top - _scrollTop));
    };
    main.fn.right = function(){
        return _element.offsetWidth + this.left();
    };
    main.fn.bottom = function(){
        return _element.offsetHeight + this.top();
    };
    main.fn.width = function (){
        //console.log("aspect:"+_element.offsetWidth);
        return _element.offsetWidth;
    };
    main.fn.height = function (){
        return _element.offsetHeight;
    };

    return new main(parameter);
};

function scaleChange(obj){
    var scale = document.getElementById('scl');

    console.log(obj.width()  +" "+obj.height() +" "+ obj.left()  +" "+obj.top());

    scale.style.width = obj.width()+'px';

    scale.style.height = obj.height()+'px';

    scale.style.left = obj.left()+'px';

    scale.style.top = obj.top()+'px';
}
function getTarget(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var targ;
    if (e.target) { targ = e.target; }
    else if (e.srcElement) { targ = e.srcElement; }
    if (targ.nodeType == 3) { targ = targ.parentNode; }
    return targ;
}

document.body.onclick = function(e){
    var _target = getTarget(e);
    if(_target.nodeName !== 'BODY'){
        var c = document.getElementById('console');
        var co = AspectViewport(_target);
        scaleChange(co);
        c.innerHTML = " left:" + co.left() + " top:" + co.top() + " right:" + co.right() + " width:" + co.width();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Problem

When you're clicking on the same element after the `scl` div has moved there, you are actually clicking on the `scl` element - it is targeting itself, and thus making itself bigger.

By itself, this should not cause an increment. However, remember that `width` and `height` include **borders**, **padding** and **margins** on elements. It increments `2px` in each dimension each click, because you have `1px` of border on each size, which is being added to the element.

### The Solution

Simply stating:

```
#scl {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

in your CSS code means that pointer events will fall through the element, and thus it can never be targeted (i.e. `pointer-events:none;` means it should be ***impossible*** to click an element with your mouse cursor) This should solve your problem.

[Working Fiddle for `pointer-events`](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0xp2um/3/)

However, if you did want the element to be clickable, you could just state that you want the `width` and the `height` of the element to always include borders, padding and margins. You can do this also in CSS.

```
#scl {
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[Working Fiddle for `box-sizing`](https://jsfiddle.net/dr0xp2um/5/)

### Notes

More about [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) and [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) can be found at MDN.

Comment: Even if it is being targeted, this should not happen, how or what is making the increment?

Comment: @AnoopMoorthy Edited to include that. It's because `width` and `height` include the border.

Comment: Glad we could help :D

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding a check to prevent scale itself to be scaled.

My fix would be to change target to body (since your code rejects body anyways) when targeting scale. Of course this is a solution when you can't use css for whatever reason.

```
function getTarget(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var targ;
  if (e.target) { targ = e.target; }
  else if (e.srcElement) { targ = e.srcElement; }
  if (targ.nodeType == 3) { targ = targ.parentNode; }
  if (targ.id === "scl") {targ = document.body; }
  return targ;
}
```